# Using multiple controllers in one view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on something like a social networking mesh; I am using different API's from various websites, e.g. Last.FM, Delicious, Twitter, ...

I've created one controller per each website (currently, there are 7).

Sample views:

```
localhost:3000/lastfm <- All datas i gathered from user's Last.fm account
localhost:3000/twitter <- All datas i gathered from user's Twitter account
...
```

Now I want to show these datas in one view (localhost:3000/index.hmtl) by using these different controllers.

Components are deprecated, creating one controller and bury all the API's in that seems ugly, too..

So I don't know how to do this. Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, you should put all of the data-storing and data-gathering methods into Resources and Models so they are accessible from all controllers. You can keep the internal data-mutating operations in your individual controllers though. Once you have it organized like this, you could do what Hobo does: create a controller just for the front page, "front_controller" if you will. Here you can display data gathered from all of your models and resources, as well as links to your other controller actions.

These are a few [interesting](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model) [thoughts](http://therailsway.com/2007/6/1/railsconf-recap-skinny-controllers) on better organizing your models and controllers (fat models, skinny controllers is a rule of thumb. 
Since you said you are using other API's (like lastfm and twitter), you might want to take a look at [this railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/121-non-active-record-model) about creating non ActiveRecord models (models that are not tied to a database)

here is some pseudo code, keep in mind its really only targeted at your question.

```
#  pseudo code  

  class TwitterController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @services = {
        :twitter => TwitterModel.find(:all, ...),
      }
    end
    def update_twitter
      TwitterUpdaterClass.update { |twit|
        _m = TwitterModel.new 
        _m.message = twit.msg
        _m.from = twit.from
        # ..
        _m.save
      }
    end
  end


  class MyIndexController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @services = {
        :twitter => TwitterModel.find(:all, ...),
        :lastfm => LastFmModel.find(:all, ...)
      }
    end
  end
```

it **might be much better** to have background-workers update your rest-services instead a controller which you need to invoke every time you want to fetch recent tweets.
here is nice article showing - [6 ways to run background jobs in rubyonrails](http://tobinharris.com/past/2009/3/9/6-ways-to-run-background-jobs-in-rubyonrails/)

```
  # more pseudo code

  class TwitterWorker < BackgrounDRb::MetaWorker
    set_worker_name :twitter_worker
    def create(args = nil) # instead of TwitterController.update_twitter
      TwitterUpdaterClass.update { |twit|
        _m = TwitterModel.new 
        _m.message = twit.msg
        _m.from = twit.from
        # ..
        _m.save
      }
    end
  end
```

Comment: (Even though this answer copies the text of the two other answers, I'm commenting here since this is the accepted answer.)

Instead of creating a non-ActiveRecord model, you can nowadays use  [ActiveModel](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activemodel), which "provides a known set of interfaces for usage in model classes. They allow for Action Pack helpers to interact with non-Active Record models, for example."

Answer (score 6):

First off, you should put all of the data-storing and data-gathering methods into Resources and Models so they are accessible from all controllers.  You can keep the internal data-mutating operations in your individual controllers though.  Once you have it organized like this, you could do what Hobo does: create a controller just for the front page, "front_controller" if you will.  Here you can display data gathered from all of your models and resources, as well as links to your other controller actions.

Comment: This.

Put your data collection into models. Searching Twitter? That's a odel. Scraping Last.fm? That's a model.  Controllers are for clients to talk to *you* - they process requests.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should read a bit about rails' [MVC architecture](http://guides.rails.info/getting_started.html#the-mvc-architecture).
It seems to me that you are neglecting the M(odel) part of it. The models should hold the data, thus being the most important part of your application.
These are a few [interesting](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model) [thoughts](http://www.therailsway.com/2007/6/1/railsconf-recap-skinny-controllers) on better organizing your models and controllers (*fat models, skinny controllers* is a rule of thumb. 
 Since you said you are using other API's (like lastfm and twitter), you might want to take a look at [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/121-non-active-record-model) about creating non ActiveRecord models (models that are not tied to a database)

If you also provide an API for your users, I suggest using a RESTful approach, as it can really be easy to develop and maintain once you get the hang of it. 
You should read more about [resources](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html), as your `localhost/lastfm` and `localhost/twitter` are resources and **not** views.

Hope this helps. Good luck